# Custom or different URL path for menu item in Joomla 3.4

Tags: url, joomla, path, jmenuitem

How can I change the URL path of menu item? For example I have menu like this:

```
- level_1
  - level_1_1
  - level_1_2
- level_2
  - level_2_1
    - level_2_1_1
    - level_2_1_2
  - level_2_2
- ...
```

and if I click on item `level_2_1_2` I don't want to have url: `/level_2/level_2_1/level_2_1_2` but only `/level_2_1_2`.

Is this possible?

Or can this be done in reverse, so I will have item named `level_2_1_2` at the menu root so the URL will be correct => `/level_2_1_2` but than menu items in the path `/level_2/level_2_1/level_2_1_2` must have `'active'` and/or `'current'` class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is very much possible.

1. Set up a second menu called "hidden menu" or something like that
2. Each item in your current menu needs to be moved to this hidden menu, without the nesting.  Just add each item as top level without nesting.
3. Go back to your original menu and make them all "menu item alias" instead of "single article, etc..." And point to the hidden menu item that you established in the last step.  https://docs.joomla.org/Help34:Menus_Menu_Item_Menu_Item_Alias

Done.  Now when you click inside your nested menu, it's actually an alias link to your hidden menu which are all published as un-nested menu items.

Can probably be done by .htaccess too, but this is an easy way I have done it.

Comment: I have done this, but it doesn't work. There must be something else what is wrong.

Comment: Are you using an SEF tool like sh404SEF?

Comment: I'm not using any external plugin/component/module etc.. It is clear Joomla system without any third-party plugins.